# Coding a fixed toggle navigation menu while disabling page scroll?

Tags: jquery, menu, responsive-design, scroll

I've seen this effect on many websites but a great example can be found on the Tuts+ redesign(code.tutsplus.com). When the browser window is resized smaller, the navigation menu turns into a hamburger icon.

When this menu is closed you can scroll up and down the full length of the page.

[screenshot with menu closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6PzJ.jpg), notice the scrollbar size.

Once this menu is open the page becomes locked to a smaller height based on the menu height. So you can't scroll down to read more articles until the menu is closed again - almost like the menu becomes the primary focus of the page.

Here's [another screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0Nl1.jpg) with the menu open - see how the scrollbar is much smaller?

I'm assuming this requires jQuery but how do you force the page to disable scrolling even when there's more content? Thanks in advance for any help.